# Cancelar o evento de click da tag <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso criar um função em JavaScript que é chamada ao clicar em um botão e deve cancelar o click de uma tag `<a>`.

Tentei desta forma:

```
$("#botao").click(function(){
  $("a").unbind('click')
})
```

Porém ao clicar na tag  ela continua mandando para o link do seu atributo href. Já tentei também com `.off('click')`, mas também sem sucesso.

Depois de cancelar o click preciso ter a possibilidade de voltar com o evento de click.

Comment: E retirar o href ao clicar no botao, nao pode ser?

Comment: Não pois talvez precise utilizar este link depois. Tenho que ter a possibilidadede cancelar e voltar o evento de click

Comment: O jQuery tem o `.one(` que só corre uma vez, mas não sei se é isso que procuras pois a pergunta está pouco clara. Podes explicar melhor, mostrar algum HTML e dar exemplos de ações e o que esperas que aconteça?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rersolvi inserindo um atributo data ao link que se está true prossegue com o get senão faz um return false.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar jQuery para obter esse resultado, segue o exemplo.

Clique uma vez e remova o link, clique novamente e adicione o link.

```js
$( ".remover-link" ).click(function() {
  $( ".link" ).each(function( i ) {
    if ($(this).attr("href") == "google.com") {
      $(this).removeAttr( "href" );
    } else {
     $(this).attr( "href", "google.com");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="link" href="google.com">Google.com</a><br>
<button class="remover-link">Remover Link</button>
```

Acho assim um pouco menos complexo que utilizar javascript puro.

Comment: Depois de cancelar o click preciso ter a possibilidade utilizar este link novamente.

Comment: Editei o código, de uma olhada novamente

Comment: Boa resposta, mas não seria melhor outro botão para adicionar o link outravez? Para exemplo só

Comment: Editei novamente rs. Agora está bem melhor

Comment: O problema é que a url do meu href é dinamica, ela vem do backend.

Comment: E como esse valor href é adicionado ao elemento <a>? Eu sabendo como o href é criado e adicionado fica mais fácil